# php month difference add 1 if one day is above

Tags: php, date

Hello I am trying calculate the difference between two dates and it works properly but the problem is even if 1 day is above to next date it counts as a whole month but in my code I am getting 8 instead of 9
here is my code

```
<?php
$date1 = '2016-09-17';
$date2 = date('Y-m-d');

$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);
$diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
echo $diff;
?>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL if there is no database related code here?

Comment: sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here will be the possible solution

```
<?php
$date_sale = '2016-09-17';
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');

$starting_date = new DateTime($date_sale);
$ending_date = new DateTime($date_now);
$interval_months = $ending_date->diff($starting_date);

$month_get =  $interval_months->format('%m'); //get months;
$up_days =  $interval_months->format('%d'); //get above days;
$show_final_months = 0;
if($up_days>0) {
    echo $show_final_months = $month_get+1;
} else {
    echo $show_final_months = $month_get;
}
?>
```